# I know its exist but ... IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, comparison

I want to compare a string char by char for the length of `thisline`. 
However, i am getting **out of range** error. Does it because of `Index`, which falls into -1 or £#$½$#£

```
def vigsquare(printable=False):
    '''
    Returns a string like a vigenere square,
    printable joins each row with a newline so it's literally square
    printable=False (defaul) joins without newlines for easier 
    searching by row and column index
    '''
    alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
    rotater = collections.deque(alpha)
    vigsquare_list = []
    for i in range(26):
        vigsquare_list.append(''.join(rotater))
        rotater.rotate(-1)
    if printable:
        return '\n'.join(vigsquare_list) 
    else:
        return ''.join(vigsquare_list)

def v(row, column):
    ''' 
    Return a character from a vigenere square by 
    row and column letter.
    vigenere('L', 'G') returns 'R'
    '''
    alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
    rowindex = alpha.find(row)
    columnindex = alpha.find(column)
    return vigsquare()[rowindex*26 + columnindex]


p = "LEMON"
Kasiski = open("c:\\HobbitStory.txt","r")

lines = Kasiski.readlines()
for i in lines:
    thisline = i.split()
    Index = len(thisline)
    while (Index>=0):
        print(v(thisline[Index],p[Index]))
        Index -= 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `Index` to the length of the line; but indexing goes to `len() - 1`, because Python uses 0-based indexing.

Subtract 1:

```
thisline = i.split()
Index = len(thisline) - 1
while Index >= 0:
    print(v(thisline[Index], p[Index]))
    Index -= 1
```

This will *still* throw an `IndexError` if there are more than 5 elements in `thisline` as `p` only has 5 characters.

It'd be easier if you used `zip()`, `reversed()` and a `for` loop:

```
thisline = i.split()
for a, b in reversed(zip(thisline, p)):
    print(v(a, b))
```

Now you are guaranteed to not run into indexing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget your imports:

```
import string
import collections
```

Now where have I seen this code before... :)